# What exception handling model does the Clang x64 Windows compiler use?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++, dwarf, seh

I've just downloaded the 3.7.1 LLVM for Windows x64 (from [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html)), and I was wondering if the clang++ inside this uses SEH exception handling or SJLJ, or something else? In particular, I believe SEH is the best on Windows for dealing with C++ exceptions thrown while behind a system call, so this compiler would be more useful to me if it uses SEH.

Comment: SEH, but only partial since LLVM does not support asynchronous exceptions.  Work is in progress, nothing loud and obvious.  Do consider the C2 backend, backgrounder in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRgWJuQhkQo), @24 minutes.

Comment: Asynchronous exceptions relates to the /EHa flag on the Microsoft cl.exe compiler, and I always use /EHsc, so I guess this means I should not notice any difference? (As relates to exceptions.)